# How to check the increase count beside a field using webdriver/Java?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a field which displays count beside it and whenever a new item is added to the field the count gets increase by one. I want to get the increased count every time to make sure that a new item is added to the field. Below is the field which displays the count

```
<span class="list-counting myone_qna_count">[2]</span>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can grab the count dynamically and validate that against a known or previous count.

```
By css = By.cssSelector(".list-counting.myone_qna_count");

//This should replace all the [] and return the count in String format
java.lang.String stCount = driver.findElement(css).getText().replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
//Parse to int so that it can be used to do the comparison
int count = Integer.parseInt(stCount);
System.out.println(count); //should be 2 now

//Do a comparison with known value here
```

Comment: My situation is like, I may not know the previous count every time. so that condition may not work for me every time.

Comment: Then take the count first and save into a variable>do whatever add/increase the count>take count again and do the comparison